# limit as x approaches zero from left and right equals positive and negative infinity

Tags: real-analysis, limits, infinity

How can we prove
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac1x &= +\infty, \\
\lim_{x\to 0^-} \frac1x &= -\infty
\end{align}

This seems really simple but I'm having trouble starting it

Comment: For the right-sided limit:  Given a number $B>0$, there exists a number $\delta >0$ such that $1/x>B$ whenever $0<x<\delta =1/B$. Can you write the proof for the left-sided limit now?

Comment: I'll try! For the right-sided limit: Given a number B>0, there exists a number δ>0 such that 1/x>B whenever δ=1/B<x<0. I'm basically saying that x is within a delta of 0, from the positive and negative sides, right? How to I prove these x's go to infinity though?

Comment: Not quite.  For the left-side:  Given a number $B<0$ (which can be $-1,000,000,000,000$ or even smaller; as small as given; ANY $B<0$), we have $1/x<B$ (that is $x$ is even "more negative") whenever, $0>x>1/B=\delta$.

Comment: right right my bad I meant to say left-sided there, but yeah I messed up on the B>0. But all these are just conditional statements. The proof isn't rigorous unless I actually specify the delta (in terms of B?) I think

Comment: I'd prefer to say that no limit exists but that's just me. Suppose I give you a big number, N = 1 million say, can you find a value d so that 1/x > N when 0 < x < d? Can you do it for a billion? A trillion? If you can always find a domain around 0+ for which 1/x exceeds any given big number then the limit of 1/x must be unbounded. Similarly for the negative side.

Comment: @TheMathemagician sure, we could say $x=1/N+1$, and $d=x+1$. So $1/x>N$ and $0<x<d$ for all $N$

Comment: @Tye We did specify the $\delta$.  For the RS: $\delta =1/B>0$.  For the LS: $\delta =-1/B$.  I inadvertently omitted the minus sign on the delta in the previous comment ... apology.  But we have it now!

Comment: We're not fixing x, it ranges over the whole domain [0, d]. We're finding a suitable d so that on that entire domain 1/x exceeds N.

Comment: @Dr.MV oh I see now. Thanks so much for helping me clear that up!

Comment: @TheMathemagician I see what you mean if we're saying x approaches zero, but if its just a one-sided limit, I don't think the limit is undefined...

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure!

Answer (score 2):

This is a very general advice, but it works every time:

If you do not know where to start, write down the definitions you know. Look at the definitions. Look especially at the definition of the thing you want to prove.

The definition of what you want to prove usually looks like

> *This thing you want to prove* is true **if and only if** *this other fancy expression is true*.

Now, you just made a first step: you now know you need to prove the "other fancy expression". If you again do not know what to do, repeat the process with that.

Comment: okay, so we say that a variable "becomes infinite" if, beginning with a certain term in a sequence of its values, the absolute value of that term and any subsequent term we might name is greater than any positive number we name, however large. So I need a delta for that works for all epsilons

Comment: @Tye See, that's what you get for not being strict. Write down, to the letter, the definition of when $\lim_{x\to a} f(x) = \infty$. I mean down to the smallest detail. Write down *everything*. You will notice there is no mention of any epsilon anywhere.

Comment: really? I was going off http://math.oregonstate.edu/home/programs/undergrad/CalculusQuestStudyGuides/SandS/lHopital/define_limit.html  and it mentions epsilon for every definition of limits.

Comment: @Tye Not if the limit is $\infty$. You **really** have to be much much *much* **much** more careful reading mathematical statements. Just in the past hour, you made several sloppy statements.

Comment: considering my primary trade is as an economist and financial analyst, and we make our living ballparking predictions of dubious accuracy, that seems to make sense haha. How would you phrase the definition, if not the $\epsilon - \delta$ way?

Comment: @Tye The link you provided is the correct one. Look at the part titled "[Negative] Infinite Limit"